# How to read a file in Crystal?

Tags: file, methods, crystal-lang

I recently picked up on Crystal after being a Rubyist for a while, and I can't seem to find anything about the File class. I want to open and read a file, but it gives me an error.

```
file = File.open("ditto.txt")
file = file.read
```

```
tequila@tequila-pc:~/code$ crystal fileopen.cr
Error in fileopen.cr:2: wrong number of arguments for 'File#read' (given 0, expected 1)
Overloads are:
 - IO::Buffered#read(slice : Bytes)
 - IO#read(slice : Bytes)

file = file.read
            ^~~~
```

Comment: Note that the error message also says `IO#read(slice : Bytes)
` – `File` inherits the `read` method from IO. According to the docs for [`IO#read`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.28.0/IO.html#read%28slice%3ABytes%29-instance-method) it expects an argument. You might want to try the [`File.read`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.28.0/File.html#read%28filename%2Cencoding%3Dnil%2Cinvalid%3Dnil%29%3AString-class-method) class method instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`IO#gets_to_end`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.28.0/IO.html#gets_to_end%3AString-instance-method) which reads the entire file as a `String`. But you might as well use [`File.read`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.28.0/File.html#read(filename,encoding=nil,invalid=nil):String-class-method)

```
file_content = File.read("ditto.txt")
```

---

[`IO#read`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.28.0/IO.html#read%28slice%3ABytes%29-instance-method) is a more low-level method which allows to read pieces of an IO into a byte slice.